# How to use ANSI C function prototypes with Oracle Pro*C?

Tags: c, oracle

I am an old hand C developer but relatively new to Pro*C development. I have inherited some Pro*C code that doesn't use ANSI prototypes, which I would to change so that it does. For most functions this is an easy process, but I'm not sure how to approach the functions that have one or more arguments that are embedded database (aka host) variables.

For example, I have a function that currently uses K&R prototypes and looks like this:

```
static long my_func (var1, var2, var3, var4)
int *var1;
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
int var2;
int var3;
char *var4;
EXEC SQL VAR var4 IS STRING (GL_CD_LEN);
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
{
    /*
     * Rest of function here...
     */
}
```

I would like to change this so that it uses proper ANSI C prototypes, but I don't know how to handle the Pro*C host variables in this context. The best I've managed to do so far is something like this:

```
static long my_func (int *var1, int func_var2, int func_var3, char *func_var4)
{
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    int var2 = func_var2;
    int var3 = func_var3;
    char *var4;
    EXEC SQL VAR var4 IS STRING (GL_CD_LEN);
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    /*
     * Rest of function here...
     */
}
```

But that doesn't strike me as being particularly elegant, and I'm not sure that I'm handling the string (`func_var4`) correctly.

I also tried the following:

```
static long my_func (int *var1, EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION; int var2, int var3, char *var4 EXEC SQL VAR var4 IS STRING (GL_CD_LEN); EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;)
{
    /*
     * Rest of function here...
     */
}
```

But that just causes Pro*C to barf with the following error:

```
Syntax error at line 7136, column 117, file EMY.i:
Error at line 7136, column 117 in file EMY.i
static long fdc_regis (int *cur_ind, EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION; int run_no,
int incl_accr_ind, char *accrgl_cd EXEC SQL VAR accrgl_cd IS STRING (41); EXEC
SQL END DECLARE SECTION;)
................................................................................
....................................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "exec sql var" when expecting one of the fol
lowing:

, ( [ exec sql end,
```

So I'm guess I'm barking up the wrong tree there! So my question is, "What's the correct way to use ANSI C function prototypes with host variable parameters in Pro*C?". All documentation I've been able to find is frustratingly quiet about this particular topic, even though host variables are otherwise covered quite well.

I'm using Pro*C/C++: Release 12.1.0.2.0 and (not that it probably matters) gcc 4.8.5 as the C compiler, on CentOS 7.4. I should also add that I am passing `parse=full code=ansi_c` (among others but these two seem to be the most pertinent) as command line arguments to `proc`.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: @JohnH, that code does compile, but I'm not sure it will work because var2 and var3 also have to be inside an EXEC SQL DECLARE SECTION.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I did Pro C, but couldn't you do your variable assignment after the declare block (the  var2 = func_var2 bit?) and keep the declare part the same as before?

Comment: A variation of that is what I've used elsewhere. It just strikes me as being a bit clumsy so I wandering whether there were a more elegant way of doing it. I guess sometimes the right answer has to be the ugly one!

Comment: one other thing I used to do I think was look at the C code that is generated by the pro*C precompiler, sometimes that can give some insight into what it is doing behind the scenes and why it is giving the error

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging, I've come up with what I think is the correct answer, which is to use a standard ANSI C prototype for the function, and then (re)declare the host variables inside an `EXEC SQL` block. Following is a small example.

Before (K&R prototype):

```
static my_func (arg1, arg2, arg3)
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    EXEC SQL VAR arg1 IS STRING (STR_LEN);
    EXEC SQL VAR arg2 IS STRING (STR_LEN);
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
int arg3
{
    /* Rest of function here... */
}
```

After (ANSI C prototype):

```
static my_func (char *arg1, char *arg2, int arg3)
{
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
        EXEC SQL VAR arg1 IS STRING (STR_LEN);
        EXEC SQL VAR arg2 IS STRING (STR_LEN);
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    /* Rest of function here... */
}
```

Thanks to everyone for their helpful pointers and advice!

Addendum 29/11/2018: If one is using plain ANSI C and sets the Pro*C MODE to ORACLE, the entire SQL Declaration section can be omitted. Here's what the Oracle documentation says: "If MODE=ORACLE, you do not have to declare host variables in a special Declare Section. However, if you do not use a Declare Section, the FIPS flagger warns you about this, as the Declare Section is part of the ANSI SQL Standard. If CODE=CPP (you are compiling C++ code) or PARSE=NONE or PARSE=PARTIAL, then you must have a Declare Section."

In my situation (just plain ANSI C, MODE=ORACLE, and PARSE=FULL), this worked like a charm!